# Can I take a first data file vector information to find and average row information in a second data file?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm running a series of analyses on several Footall games and want to be able to write a script to automate this process. For each game I have two data files in R. I want to use information from a vector in one file (always in the same position regardless of the game) to find a row in another file, and then average that row and the succeeding 9 rows.

For example:

The first data file contains Game Event information (e.g. Goal 1, Time of Event).

```
Game                          Game Event     Game Time
Everton vs. Manchester        Start Game         0
Everton vs. Manchester        Goal 1            12
Everton vs. Manchester        Goal 2            24
Everton vs. Manchester        Half Time         45
Everton vs. Manchester        Goal 3            67
Everton vs. Manchester        End Game          90
```

The second data file contains Information about Variables in the game (E.g. Game, game time (3 recordings a second), decibel level, ambient temperature).

```
Game                          Game Time       dB      Temp
Everton vs. Manchester          0.33         112       9.5
Everton vs. Manchester          0.663        115       9.6
Everton vs. Manchester          0.996        114       9.5
Everton vs. Manchester          1.329        113       9.4
```

I want to be able to use the Game Time value for the first goal and the end of the game from the first file to find the closest Game Time value in the second file. I want to use the corresponding nearest value in the second file Game Time and the following 9 rows (approximately 3 seconds of data) and average the dB and Temperature scores.

If possible, I'd like this data saving as a dataframe. E.g.:

```
Game                         Event        Mean dB      Mean Temp
Everton vs. Manchester       Goal 1        121.34        9.453
Everton vs. Manchester       End Game      115.21        9.322
```

So I would take the Event Time information from the first data set (Goal 1 -> 15), find the closest absolute value to 15 (e.g. 15.325) in the second data set, and find the average of dB and Temp for that row and the following 9 rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi..can you explain your expected output ? I am not quite sure if I understand how you got those numbers in the final output.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I wasn't clear before.

The first data set has time in minutes (e.g. 15). The second data set has 3 recordings a second (e.g. 1.00, 1.33, 1.66, 2.00). 

I want to take the first & last time point in data 1, find the closest value in data 2 (e.g. 15 -> 15.00). I then want to average that row and the 9 rows following it (e.g. 15.00, 15.33, 15.66, 16.00, 16.33, 16.66 - giving me approx. 3 seconds of data) to get average dB and temp.